# how do change my expression in part i) to help calc part ii)?

Tags: real-analysis

1. Define the function $f : [e,∞) → R$ by
   $f(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{x} , x ∈ [e,∞)$.

(i) Show that $f$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $[e, ∞)$.

(ii) Use the monotonicity of $f$ to decide which of the values $f(e), f(π)$ is the larger
one.

I have don't get part ii)
for did part i) I have stated f is continuous on $[e, ∞)$ and differentiable on $(e, ∞)$
and calc the

$f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln(x)}{x^2} < 0$ [because $(1-\ln(x))<0$ whilst $(x^2)>0$]
,$x∈(e, ∞)$

so I concluded $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(e, ∞)$.

for part ii) I know I have to manipulate my answer in part i) but how?

Comment: How are you getting that derivative if $f(x)=\ln(x)$?

Comment: I think he might have wanted it to be $\frac{\ln{x}}{x}$. Might be incorrectly formatted. I will send an edit, and OP may accept it if its correct.

Comment: "I have to manipulate my answer" -- What do you mean by "manipulate", and why do you think you need to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What does monotonicity mean? If you know that the function is **strictly decreasing** over the interval $[e, \infty)$, then as $x$ increases what is the nature of $f(x)$?, and consider the fact that $f(e) = $ maximum, and that $e < \pi$.